# iOS UI Automated Testing: How to pull down, drag or scroll in a CollectionView?

Tags: ios, testing, uicollectionview, drag, ui-automation

I am testing my app with the UI Automated Testing framework. I have a UIACollectionView I would like to pull down or drag my CollectionView. I already tried the ways from the documentation:
to drag up

```
target.dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.9}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.2}, duration:2.0});
```

or to pull down:

```
target.dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.3}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.8}, duration:2.0});
```

when this didnt work I tried to use the inheritated methods of the UIAScrollView. chatList is my UIACollectionView

```
archivedChatCell = chatList.cells()["Noise"]
archivedChatCell.scrollToElementWithValueForKey(1, "isVisible")
chatList.scrollDown()
chatList.scrollToElementWithPredicate("Noise")
```

But nothing is moving in the screen. I read in some threads that this (dragInsideWithOptions) is a Apple problem that needs to be fixed for the iOS7 UI Testing.
Does someone have any idea what the problem is? Am I missing something or is there a work around for that?
The weird thing is, I am using the same code in a different CollectionView in my App, the dragInsideWithOptions works fine and drags or pulls the screen.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dragInsideWithOptions and flickInsideWithOptions are not working on the simulator. However, they do work on a real device. Therefore, my suggestion is to use a real device until Apple fixes the problem.

Comment: but thats the thing, I get this function to work in other screens, and this are CollectionViews as well. But just not on my RootViewController, what is as well a CollectionView...really strange behaviour...??!!

Comment: Yeah it's a bit strange but you can get the array of cells to find the index which can give you the "current cell", then just go through each cell using the **scrollToElementWithName** method and that might do the trick.